# Как проверить, что страница напечаталась?

Tags: javascript, print

Коллеги, у меня задача. Одна страница открывает pdf в отдельной вкладке и дальше нужно сделать так чтобы после печати страница закрывалась. Как это сделать?

```
loadPDF() {
        const reloadButtonElement = this.querySelector('#reload');
        const linkToPdf = `/adress-api/rest/doc-confirmation/${this.confirmationId}/?output-type=pdf`;

        reloadButtonElement.setAttribute('href', linkToPdf);


        $('#reload').click(function(){
            let newWindow = window.open(linkToPdf, '_blank');
            newWindow.onload = function(){

                if(newWindow.print == 'true'){
                    newWindow.close();
                }

                newWindow.console.log("Закрылось");
            }

        });
```

Comment: Еще мне не совсем понятно, чего вы пытались добиться выражением `newWindow.print == 'true'`. Во-первых, что это за свойство такое, а во-вторых - вы точно уверены, что нужно именно нестрогое сравнение со строкой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать воспользоваться событием [`afterprint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/afterprint):

> The `afterprint` event is fired after the associated document has started printing or the print preview has been closed.
>
> Событие `afterprint` происходит после того, как документ начал печататься, или окно печати было закрыто.

"...после того, как документ начал печататься..." - по идее, после начала печати окно печати автоматически закрывается, поэтому событие срабатывает и при явном закрытии, и при закрытии, вызванном началом печати.

```
newWindow.addEventListener("afterprint", function(event) {
    newWindow.close();
});
```